# Play video from PHP file on my web page

Tags: php

I have this file PHP:

```
$url = 'http://page.com/file.flv';

header('Content-Type: application/x-flv');
header ("Content-Length: " . filesize($url));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.flv");

$fd = fopen($url, "r");
while(!feof($fd))
{
    echo fread($fd, 4096);
    ob_flush();
}
```

And then I'm trying to start watch this video on my web page:

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="file.php" type="video/x-flv">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

But I always get error 'Can't open file'. When I'm trying to add url which contain .flv in the end of url string (not .php) - everything is OK.

Where is a problem?

Comment: Try to give complete path to your file firstly

Comment: I must do it using readfile or fread. I can't give complete path in HTML code because url is generated by another web page for IP. So if I get this URL using CURL and then add this url to video tag - it doesn't work because my web server and client/user have not similar IP addresses.